# Advice for optimization of a custom doubly Linked List class

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my custom implementation of a double Linked list. Code is apparently working fine. Need advices on improvement and/or optimization. This is a tiny academic side-project. I am still pretty green to C++ .

Would also want to know what are the differences between all sorts of custom implementations and STL implementations. If it's about memory safety, I would also want to learn how my code is memory unsafe.

Edit: Class implementation, invocation and output

Class Implementation goes here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class dLinkedList
{
public:

    //constructors will go here
    dLinkedList(int value)
    {
        createFirstNode(value);
        nodeCount = new size_t;
        updateNodeCount();
    }
    dLinkedList() : dLinkedList(0) {} //delegated constructor;

    //class destructor will go here
    ~dLinkedList()
    {
        deleteList();
        delete nodeCount;
        nodeCount = nullptr;
    }

    //member functions will go here
    void append(int);                   // will attach a new node at the end of the list
    void prepend(int);                  // will insert a new node at the beginning of the list
    bool insertNode(int, int, bool, bool);   // will insert a new node after the existing node (true = first occurrence from the head with value int OTHERWISE if false, then from the tail.)
    bool deleteNode(int, bool);        // will delete the existing node (true = first occurrence from the head with value int OTHERWISE if false, then from the tail.)
    void dock();                        // will delete the last node in the list
    void decapitate();                  // will delete the first node in the list
    size_t getNodeCount();              // will return the number of nodes - experimental feature
    void printList(bool);               // will print the values of the data - (true for ordered list, false for reverse ordered list)

private:
    //defining the double linked-list structure
    struct Node
    {
        int data {0}; //this is a generic place holder - will be replaced later with some actual data-structures
        Node *next {nullptr};
        Node *previous {nullptr};

        Node() = default;
        Node(int x) : data(x) {}
    };

    //member functions go here
    void createFirstNode(int val);  //will create the first node when the list is empty
    void deleteList();  // will be called when class destructor is called
    void updateNodeCount(); // keeps the nodeCount variable up-to-date
    bool isListEmpty(); // returns true if the list is empty

    //member variables go here
    Node *head {nullptr};
    Node *tail {nullptr};
    size_t *nodeCount {nullptr}; //experimental feature
};

void dLinkedList::createFirstNode(int val)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;
    head = temp;
    tail = head; //tail and head are same - implying only one node
}

void dLinkedList::deleteList()  // will be called when class destructor is called
{
    if(isListEmpty()) //to check whether the list is already empty i.e. null
        return; //then job is already done and there is nothing to do
    else
    {
        while(head != tail)
            dock();

        delete head;
        head = tail = nullptr;
    }
}

bool dLinkedList::isListEmpty()
{
    return (head == nullptr || tail == nullptr);
}

void dLinkedList::append(int val)
{
    if(isListEmpty()) // if the list is empty - construct first node
    {
        createFirstNode(val);
        updateNodeCount();
        return;
    }

    Node *pointer = tail;
    //we are at the end of the list i.e. the tail
    //creating a new temporary node and assigning values
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;

    //Now the new temp node becomes the tail
    temp->previous = pointer;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    tail = temp;

    pointer->next = tail; //previous tail becomes the last but one entry

    updateNodeCount();
}

void dLinkedList::prepend(int val)
{
    if(isListEmpty()) // if the list is empty - construct first node
    {
        createFirstNode(val);
        updateNodeCount();
        return;
    }

    Node *pointer = head;
    //pointing at the head
    //now creating a new temp node and assigning value
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;

    //this new temp will become the head
    temp->previous = nullptr;
    temp->next = pointer;
    head = temp;

    //previous head becomes the second entry
    pointer->previous = head;

    updateNodeCount();
}

void dLinkedList::dock()
{
    //to check whether the list is empty
    if(isListEmpty())
    {
        updateNodeCount();
        return;
    }

    //To check whether tail = head (implying only one entry in the list)
    if(head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr; //list is empty
    }
    else
    {
        //first declaring a Node ptr and assigning the new node as tail
        Node *prev_tail = tail->previous;

        //current tail is cut off (docked)
        delete tail;

        //new tail is the previous last but one entry
        tail = prev_tail;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }
    updateNodeCount();
}

void dLinkedList::decapitate()
{
    //to check whether the list is empty
    if(isListEmpty())
    {
        updateNodeCount();
        return;
    }

    //To check whether tail = head (implying only one entry in the list)
    if(head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr; //list is empty
    }
    else
    {
        //first declaring a Node ptr and assigning the new node as tail
        Node *prev_head = head->next;

        //current head is cut off (decapitated)
        delete head;

        //new head is the previous second entry
        head = prev_head;
        head->previous = nullptr;
    }
    updateNodeCount();
}

void dLinkedList::updateNodeCount()
{
    if(isListEmpty()) //implying empty list
    {
        *nodeCount = 0;
    }

    if(head == tail) //implying only one entry in the list
    {
        *nodeCount = 1;
        return;
    }

    *nodeCount = 0;
    Node *traverser = head;
    while(traverser != nullptr)
    {
        ++*nodeCount;
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
}

bool dLinkedList::deleteNode(int valueToSearchFor, bool order = true) // if false then searches from the tail
{
    if(isListEmpty())
        return false;

    bool matchFound {false};

    if(order)
    {
        Node *traverser = head;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            if(traverser->data == valueToSearchFor)
            {
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
            traverser = traverser->next;
        }

        if(matchFound)
        {
            Node *prev = traverser->previous;
            Node *next = traverser->next;

            prev->next = next;
            next->previous = prev;
        }

        delete traverser;
        traverser = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *traverser = tail;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            if(traverser->data == valueToSearchFor)
            {
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
            traverser = traverser->previous;
        }

        if(matchFound)
        {
            Node *prev = traverser->previous;
            Node *next = traverser->next;

            prev->next = next;
            next->previous = prev;
        }

        delete traverser;
        traverser = nullptr;
    }

    updateNodeCount();
    return matchFound;
}

bool dLinkedList::insertNode(int valueToSearchFor, int valueOfNewNode, bool order = true, bool insertionPosition = true)
{
    //if order = false, then searches from the tail
    //if insertionPosition = false, then insert the new node BEFORE the searched node

    if(isListEmpty())
        return false;

    bool matchFound {false};

    if(order)
    {
        Node *traverser = head;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            if(traverser->data == valueToSearchFor)
            {
                matchFound = true;
                break; //at this point the traverser is holding the address of the exact node, we are searching for
            }
            traverser = traverser->next;
        }

        if(insertionPosition)
        {
            if(traverser == tail)
            {
                append(valueOfNewNode);
                updateNodeCount();
                return matchFound;
            }

            //create a new node
            Node *temp = new Node;
            temp->data = valueOfNewNode;
            //the previous of the new node will be the traverser node itself
            temp->previous = traverser;
            //the next of the new node will point to the address of traverser's next
            Node *nodeAfterTraverser = traverser->next;
            temp->next = nodeAfterTraverser;
            //the new node is now next to the traverser now (after insertion)
            traverser->next = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(traverser == head)
            {
                prepend(valueOfNewNode);
                updateNodeCount();
                return matchFound;
            }

            Node *newPtr = new Node;
            newPtr->data = valueOfNewNode;
            newPtr->next = traverser;
            newPtr->previous = traverser->previous;

            newPtr->previous->next = newPtr;

            traverser->previous = newPtr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node *traverser = tail;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            if(traverser->data == valueToSearchFor)
            {
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
            traverser = traverser->previous;
        }

        if(insertionPosition)
        {
            if(traverser == tail)
            {
                append(valueOfNewNode);
                updateNodeCount();
                return matchFound;
            }

            //create a new node
            Node *temp = new Node;
            temp->data = valueOfNewNode;
            //the previous of the new node will be the traverser node itself
            temp->previous = traverser;
            //the next of the new node will point to the address of traverser's next
            Node *nodeAfterTraverser = traverser->next;
            temp->next = nodeAfterTraverser;
            //the new node is now next to the traverser now (after insertion)
            traverser->next = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(traverser == head)
            {
                prepend(valueOfNewNode);
                updateNodeCount();
                return matchFound;
            }

            Node *newPtr = new Node;
            newPtr->data = valueOfNewNode;
            newPtr->next = traverser;
            newPtr->previous = traverser->previous;

            newPtr->previous->next = newPtr;

            traverser->previous = newPtr;
        }
    }

    updateNodeCount();
    return matchFound;
}

size_t dLinkedList::getNodeCount()
{
    return *nodeCount;
}

void dLinkedList::printList(bool order = true)
{
    if(head == nullptr || tail==nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "\nNo entries in the list.";
        return;
    }

    if(order)
    {
        std::cout << "\nPrinting ordered list (first to last):\t[total entries: " << getNodeCount() << "]";
        Node *traverser = head;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << traverser->data;
            traverser = traverser->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nPrinting reverse-ordered list (last to first):\t[total entries: " << getNodeCount() << "]";
        Node *traverser = tail;
        while(traverser != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << traverser->data;
            traverser = traverser->previous;
        }
    }
}
```

And invoking function goes here:

```
int main()
{
    dLinkedList trial;
    trial.decapitate();
    trial.printList();

    trial.append(8);
    trial.append(0);
    trial.append(16);

    trial.prepend(16);
    trial.prepend(71);

    trial.printList();

    trial.dock();
    trial.printList();

    trial.decapitate();
    trial.printList();

    trial.insertNode(0, 1004, false, false);
    trial.insertNode(0, 241, true, true);
    trial.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

And the output of the invocation:

```
No entries in the list.
Printing ordered list (first to last):  [total entries: 5]
71
16
8
0
16
Printing ordered list (first to last):  [total entries: 4]
71
16
8
0
Printing ordered list (first to last):  [total entries: 3]
16
8
0
Printing ordered list (first to last):  [total entries: 5]
16
8
1004
0
241
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.396 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: A boring optimization tip for doubly linked lists is to avoid using doubly linked lists, obviously that doesn't help if the goal is to try implementing a doubly linked list..

Comment: @harold Generally the least appreciated though most needed advice.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

#### Design

1. If you default-construct your list, it contains a single element with value `0`.
   Very surprising.
2. Make nodes just dumb structs, anything more will get in the way of the list, especially when you get to xvalues and emplacing. Remember it is just an implementation-detail of the list, and not oart of the interface, so needs no encapsulation.
3. An empty list is fundamentally different to a non-empty list in your design, which is reflected in all functions adding or removing elements.
   Consider making it a fully circular list, and thus eliminating special cases.

   ```
   class list {
       struct links {
           links *next;
           links *last;
       };
       struct node {
           links links;
           int data;
       };
       links links { &links, &links };
       std::size_t count;
       ...
   ```
4. Try to mirror the interface of [`std::list`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).
   Doing so is not just key to interfacing with all generic code, but will reduce any users effort needed to use it.
   As an added bonus, you can throw out some of the current members.
5. `nodeCount` should be a `std::size_t`, not a pointer to a dynamically allocated one. The extra allocation and indirection are wasteful.

#### Implementation

1. If your class manages its own resources (nodes), the implicitly declared defaulted copy-/move- ctor/assignment are wrong.
   Define your own doing the right thing.
2. `!head`, `!tail`, and `!*nodeCount` are all true for an empty list, and false otherwise. Check either, but and-ing or or-ing them is just a waste. If you want, you could always `assert()` your invariant to ease initial debugging though.
3. A member of list really shouldn't be named for being list-related.
   Names should be as brief as possible while giving the relevant info and avoiding all but the most well-established abbreviations. A smaller scope means less information is needed.
4. It's nice that you keep track of your lists size. Except that you don't quite do that, recounting the whole list on adding or removing a node. What a waste, you already know what you did!
5. Do not repeat your code in comments, or they easily become wrong and even more irrelevant.
   Comments should explain why you do things, and explain things which aren't obvious from scanning the code, not distract and bore you. And then there are doc-comments...
6. Don't null a pointer just before it gets destroyed.
   Or would you repaint a house just before calling in the wrecking-crew? Newly white walls are neither easier nor harder to demolish.
7. If a function cannot throw an exception by design, mark it `noexcept`. This signals your guarantee to the user and calling code, allowing them to benefit.
8. Mark non-mutating member-functions `const`. Const-correctness is a great tool allowing the compiler to catch programmer errors, even if it necessitates some code duplication.
9. Dito for `constexpr`, when you get to it.
10. Avoid `std::endl`. If you actually need an explicit manual flush, be explicit and use `std::flush`. Nearly always, you are just crippling your efficiency.
11. Mark single-argument ctors `explicit` unless you really want to use them for implicit conversions.
12. `std::size_t` is not guaranteed to be a member of the global namespace with your includes. Just be explicit.
13. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: !head == !tail is always true, thus checking both in isListEmpty() is wasteful.

Then how do I check whether I am dealing with an empty list.

Comment: If your class manages its own resources, defaulted copy-/move- ctor/assignment are wrong.
I tried to use a dedicated resource function during ctors/dtors - haven't used any defaulted copy. OR maybe I am not getting what you are advising.

Comment: Don't bother with repainting the house just before calling in the wrecking-crew. Newly white walls are neither easier nor harder to demolish.

I am quite sure I couldn't follow the context and your suggestion.

Comment: Mark the relevant members noexcept respectively constexpr. It will document your guarantees and allow calling code to benefit.
Can you kindly explain - how do I do that.
There any function/variable in the class worthy of constexpr.
noexcept - even though I am familiar, but don't know where and why and how to use it.

Comment: Also, I couldn't decipher - Make nodes just dumb structs, anything more will get in the way of the list, especially when you get to xvalues and emplacing.
Kindly elaborate.

Comment: A) If you have two equivalent conditions you could check to determine whether something is true, either is sufficient. If you want, you could always assert your invariants. B) A resource-function? What is that? And the list should manage its nodes itself. [Move-/Copy- ctor/assignment are implicitly declared and defined for you](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) as you didn't declare them. C) Why null a pointer in the dtor, just before it gets destroyed? D) expanded E) Remove all ctors and ssuch from the node, as it is just an implementation--detail of the list and gets in the way.

Comment: A) Got your point - will only check with either one of them.
B) The list manages its nodes on its own through member functions - so where is my error? Kindly be specific.
C) I used nullptr AFTER deleting the pointer - which is a safe practice according to Bjarne Stroustrup (in his Programming & Principles book)
D)expanded ? What? Either you respond in full, please or do NOT respond at all. I searched google but could find any context to expand.
E) Since I am not using smart pointers, stack overflow recommends to deallocate the memory MANUALLY in the destructors.

Comment: B) Using a resource-function reads like delegating resource management to it, not that you do. C) Whatever he wrote, at best nulling the pointer is useless, as it gets destroyed shortly after. D), expanded means my post above. The single point was expanded to three, with two getting a bit more meat added, the third needing to much extra knowledge to handle it now, and not being nearly as important. E) Ehm, ...? I meant all the logic is and belongs in the list itself, putting any in the node complicates things.